# How to load html string asynchronously in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am parsing the html string in tableview cell. Parsing this string is causing me a main thread block and performance issues while scrolling.

I tried to do the html string parsing in another global queue and render it in Application in main Queue as below:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Test", qos: .userInteractive)
    queue.async {
        let fontModifiedString = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 16 \">%@</span>" as NSString, htmlStr)
        let stringWithoutNewLine = fontModifiedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
        do {
            let htmlAttrStr = try NSAttributedString(
                data: stringWithoutNewLine.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                documentAttributes: nil)
            print("html string \(htmlStr)")
            let fontAttribute = [.foregroundColor: htmlStringColor] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: htmlAttrStr)
            mutableAttributedString.addAttributes(fontAttribute, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: htmlAttrStr.length))
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

However, i am not able to see the html string. It displays me the normal text. This has improved the performance but does not displays the html string in Application?

How do you display html string in tableview cells without performance degradation?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you display html string in tableview cells without performance degrade

It sounds like you're trying to do this in `cellForRowAt`. But you can't do anything time consuming in `cellForRowAt`, as you must return the cell immediately. And you can't do anything asynchronous in `cellForRowAt` (such as calculating on a background thread), for the same reason — you must return the cell immediately, i.e. before the asynchronous calculation has even taken place.

This is really just a variation on the standard problem of fetching images asynchronously for use in a table view. Basically you have to use prefetching to kick off the process, and have the table view cell use a temporary placeholder. Then you put the data, when it is ready, not into the cell but into the *data model*. Then you reload the table view row that has just become ready, and this time `cellForRowAt` finds the data ready immediately in the model and uses it.

Comment: Yes! However, my main question is why the code doesn't render html string in background thread. I can see only plain text with the above code. At least if the UI doesn't hang on main thread, it's possible there wont be any performance issues with main thread blocking while scrolling.

Comment: It does render the string. But by that time the cell has already been returned.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same problem when trying to parse HTML to NSAtributedString on dequeueReusableCell. Based on @matt 's comment, I moved all of the code using for the conversion into the model and executed the conversion before putting data into the dequeueReusableCell. It worked pretty well.

The reason for not displaying the NSAttrbitedString might be because your cell got executed or intialised before the parsing process got done. Thus, the parsed HTML is there but not displaying into the UI until the next lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

Use your HTML string in the htmlresponse  i get and then use the below function to show html in required format.

```
let htmlResponse:String = "\((Obj.HTMLStr)!)”
let myText = "<span style=\"font-family: Poppins-SemiBold; font-size: 14\">\(htmlResponse)</span>"
self.myView?.lbl_PolicyText.attributedText = self.stringFromHtml(string: myText)
self.myView?.lbl_PolicyText.sizeToFit()
```

Convert HTML TO STRING FUNC

```
// MARK:- HTML TO STRING
func stringFromHtml(string: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    do {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        if let d = data {
            let str = try NSAttributedString(data: d,
                                             options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:  NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                                             documentAttributes: nil)
            return str
        }
    } catch {
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference?